# Group By and Count using nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, count, group-by

Imagine the following tables :

> **Tag** (TagId, Label)
>
> **Post** (PostId, Title, Content)
>
> **User** (UserId, Name)
>
> **UserPostTag** (Id, UserId, PostId, TagId)

For a Post, multiple users can add one or more Tag.

I want to get, via nHibernate, the tag list for a post, with the count of each Tag.

Exemple or result :

```
Tag(id1, label1), 7

Tag(id2, label2), 5

Tag(id3, label3), 2
```

I know how to get list of tags for a post :

```
IList<Tag> tagList = session.CreateCriteria<Tag>()
 .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("TagId",
     DetachedCriteria.For<UserPostTag>()
         .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Post.PostId", 17))
         .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Tag.TagId"))
     ))
     .List<Tag>();
```

Can you please help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Sorry for my english ...

Sincerely,

Antoine

Comment: The following query do almost what I want (I remove the restriction on Post id) :

IList tagList = session.CreateQuery("select tag.Id, tag.Label, count(cloud.User) "
+ "from UserPostTag cloud join cloud.Tag tag "
+ "group by tag.Id, tag.Label").List();

The problem is that want to get a an array of Tag / count.

Have you got an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, create the HQL query like this:

```
@"SELECT new Tag(tag.Id, tag.Label), count(cloud.User)
FROM UserPostTag cloud 
    JOIN cloud.Tag tag
WHERE cloud.Post.Id = :postId
GROUP BY tag.Id, tag.Label"
```

Enter this in the CreateQuery call, it works only if you have a constructor on Tag which accepts an id and a label. (Don't forget to set the postId parameter.)

This returns a list with tag and list in an array, I believe.

Update: if this does not work, you can create a new class TagCount which has a tag and a count and change the select syntax to something like the following:

```
SELECT new TagCount(tag.Id, tag.Label, count(cloud.User))
```

(Disclaimer: I did not try this.)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would make an extra member for the Post class, name it Tags and map it as many to many to your UserPostTag table. In this case you can use the following code to get your task done:

**Make a class to retreive your results:**

```
class TagWithCount
{
  public string Label {get;set;}
  public int Count {get;set;}
}
```

**Create a query (using QueryOver):**

```
Tag ta = null;
TagWithCount res = null;

var query = QueryOver.Of<Post>()
  .JoinAlias(x=>x.Tags, ()=>ta)
  .SelectList(x=>x.SelectGroup(() => ta.Label).WithAlias(() => res.Label),
                  .SelectCount(p=>p.Id).WithAlias(() => res.Count))
  .Where(x=>x.Id == postId)
  .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<TagWithCount>());
```

**Select the actual result:**

```
var res = query.GetExecutableQueryOver(session).List<TagWithCount> ();
```

P.S.: I haven't check if the code completely correct, it is just to give an idea.